# What special characters need to be escaped when insert String literal to database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using jdbc to insert data to database. For some reasons, I can't use PreparedStatement, I have to execute query directly. What special characters do I have to escape ?. I only know about the single quote(') and the backslash().

Edit: The reason I can't use PreparedStatement is, my app receive json data from server and its values are always represented as String.
For example :

```
{
 "tableName": "movies",
  "data": [
     "The Big Lewbowski",
     "119",
    "1998-06-03"
]
}
```

It mean now I have to insert the data to the table movies.
I can only deserialize the data to a List
Now if I use PrepareStatement.

```
    String sql = "insert into movies values(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    System.out.println(ps.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < newData.size(); i++) {
        ps.setObject(i + 1, newData.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(ps.toString());

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6267c3bb: insert into movies values(** NOT SPECIFIED **,**       NOT SPECIFIED **,** NOT SPECIFIED **)
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@6267c3bb: insert into movies values('The Big        Lewbowski','117','1998-06-03')
```

As you can see , it doesn't work. my movies table have the different column types :
    movies(title varchar,runtime int,releaseDate Date);
It can insert the data but there must been implicit conversion, right?

Comment: Please paste sample PreparedStatement construction and errors. We are not able to guess what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Why can't you use a `PreparedStatement` - that sounds like a totally useless restriction (plus it's a security risk) Btw: the backslash \ does *not* need to be escaped in SQL.

Comment: "For some reasons"? What reasons? You should do everything possible to use parameterized SQL... escaping it manually is error-prone and fundamentally a bad idea.

Comment: Yup, yup and yup. No good reason for you to not use PreparedStatement, unless you're looking to expose yourself to sql injection.

Comment: so your ***real*** question is: How do I convert a JSON document to proper Java objects that I can use in a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry for my bad English. Well I have the data, now I just need to insert it into my table. I thought I can do it with insert statement dirrectly, just need to surround the data with two single quotes if it's string literal and escape special charater properly . Isn't that what PreparedStatement does?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name And why do you say " the backslash \ does not need to be escaped in SQL". I don't know other DBMS but in Mysql when  inserting the backslash I have to double it (\\)

Comment: @user2747502 In SQL (the language) the backslash has no special meaning. If MySQL does this differently then it's violating the SQL standard (which doesn't surprise me at all)

Answer (score 3):

> The reason I can't use PreparedStatement is, my app receive json data from server and its values are always represented as String

That's a non-sequitur. You should be able to determine the schema from your database, and then work out how to convert each JSON value appropriately. Aside from anything else, the format in JSON may not be the same as the format the database would expect anyway.

*Don't* throw away security by just including the values directly in the SQL: perform the conversions in your code, and use `PreparedStatement` with parameterized values.

Your next tasks should be to:

- Work out how to get the schema information from the database (this is standard JDBC)
- Check that you know what format will be used for each of the various types of data (dates in particular can be a pain) so you can convert them
- Write *lots* of tests - note that the conversion part can be entirely isolated from JDBC, and very testable.

Comment: Thank you, I've found a way, I get the resultsetmetadata of the table I want to insert, get the java.sql.Types of each column, and then use the preparedStatement.setObject((int parameterIndex, Object x,int targetSqlType). What do you think? Is there better way?

Comment: @user2747502: Well you missed out the step where you convert the JSON value, but yes, that's basically the idea.

Comment: But Mr Skeet, I know that we have to use preparedStatement to prevent Sql injection but I notice It just surround the data with single quote if It's setString or setDate and if it's numeric(setInt,setDouble...) it don't. And it have to escape the string also. As far as I know ,in Mysql there are only two character need to be escaped when inserting that are the backslash and single quote

Comment: @user2747502: No, it doesn't "just surround the data with a single quote". You don't need to do any escaping at all. I would actually expect it not to build a SQL statement including the values at all - instead, I'd expect it to send the values separately from the SQL. However, if it *does* build the SQL statement with values itself, you should be able to trust the driver to do the right escaping. Either way, *you don't need any escaping* if you're using PreparedStatement parameters.

Comment: @JonSkeet The MySQL JDBC driver by default rewrites the query with the parameter values escaped and embedded inside the query; it doesn't prepare the query once nor send the parameter values separately like most databases. However there is a config option to enable this iirc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks for the extra detail.